# Long-double-linked-list

Tags: python, class, long-integer, doubly-linked-list

I have a problem with the code. The code gives an error and it says that Node does not have a "previous" in the __add__() operator however it doesnt give an error in the main program
The point of the assignment is to create a long using linked list

> ```
> class Node():
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.next = None
>         self.prev = None
>         self.data = None
>
>     def getData(self):
>         return self.data
>
> class LinkedList():
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.count = 0
>         self.last = Node()
>         self.first = Node()
>         self.first.next = self.last
>         self.last.previous = self.first
>
>     def append(self, data):
>         self.last.data = data
>         self.last.next = Node()
>         tmp = self.last
>         self.last = self.last.next
>         self.last.previous = tmp
>         self.count += 1
>
>     def prepend(self, data):
>         self.first.data = data
>         self.first.previous = Node()
>         tmp = self.first
>         self.first = self.first.previous
>         self.first.next = tmp
>         self.count += 1
>
>     def front(self):
>         if self.count == 0: return None
>         return self.first.next
>
>     def back(self):
>         if self.count == 0: return None
>         return self.last.previous
>
>     def size(self):
>         return self.count
>
>     def __getitem__(self, node):
>         count = self.first
>         while count.data:
>             if count.data == node:
>                 return count
>             count = count.next
>         return None
>
>     def __iter__(self):
>         count = self.first.next
>         while count.data:
>             print("here")
>             yield count.data
>             count = count.next
>
> class BigInt:
>     def __init__(self, initValue = "0"):
>         self.data = LinkedList()
>         for count in initValue:
>             self.data.append(count)
>         self.Neg = False
>
>     def __repr__(self):
>         integer = ""
>         node = self.data.front()
>         while node.next:
>             integer= integer+(node.getData())
>             node = node.next
>         return "".join(integer)
>
>     def toString(self):
>         return self.__repr__()
>
>     def isNeg(self):
>         return self.Neg
>
>     def __add__(self, rhs):
>         node1 = self.data.back()
>         node2 = rhs.data.back()
>         if self.isNeg() and not rhs.isNeg():
>             return rhs - self
>         elif rhs.isNeg() and not self.isNeg():
>             return self - rhs
>
>         summation = LinkedList()
>         carryOne = 0
>         print(node1.previous.previous.getData())
>         while node1.previous.getData() is not None or node2.previous.getData() is not None:
>             tot = int(node1.getData())+int(node2.getData())+carryOne
>             summation.prepend((tot)%10)
>             carryOne = 0
>             if tot >= 10: carryOne = 1
>             node1 = node1.previous
>             node2 = node2.previous
>         ret = ""
>         for digit in summation:
>             ret = ret + digit
>             print(digit)
>         print (ret)
>
>     def __sub__():
>         pass
>
> a = LinkedList()
> a.prepend(4)
> a.prepend(5)
> a.append(23)
> print (type(a.back()))
> print(a.back().previous.previous.getData())
>
> g = BigInt("2")
> h = BigInt("3")
> (g+h)
> print (g.toString())
> ```

Comment: (doulbly) linked lists are low level primitives in information processing. In Python you typically do not implement this yourself. You should just use the built-in List data type. If you need additional methods to implement a specific interface you can easily derive a new class from List.

Comment: @Ber In Python, `collections.deque` is a doubly linked list. `list` is actually an array.

Answer (score 4):

There's no `previous` member in a newly-constructed `Node`, only `prev`.

Some instances of `Node` will later acquire a member called `previous`. This is due to code like:

```
self.last.previous = self.first
```

(Thanks to @David Robinson for pointing that out.)

Comment: however the last .previous in (print(a.back().previous.previous.getData())) doesnt give an error

Comment: @user1775641: That's because of the line `self.last.previous = self.first`. Sometimes it will have a `.previous`, but not always.

Comment: Oh ok... is there a way to fix it? Thanks! Also... don't I give a previous to every Node?

Comment: @user1775641: the way to fix it is not to use prev and previous as if they're interchangeable. Pick one and stick to it.